# Could not find files on devDependencies

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I have a package.json file that looks as following:

```
{
  "name": "basics",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "3.4.0",
    "react-scripts": "1.0.14",
    "fsr-helpers": "file:../../fsr-helpers"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "history": "4.3.0",
    "prop-types": "15.6.0",
    "react": "16.0.0",
    "react-dom": "16.0.0",
    "react-router-dom": "4.2.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "e2e": "nightwatch",
    "run-e2e": "./node_modules/.bin/concurrently -k 'npm start' 'npm run e2e'"
  }
}
```

During the installation of packages, I've got the following error message:

```
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: core-js@2.4.1 (node_modules/fsr-helpers/node_modules/babel-polyfill/node_modules/core-js):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/home/developer/Desktop/fullstack-react-code/routing/basics/node_modules/.staging/core-js-4f416826' -> '/home/developer/Desktop/fullstack-react-code/fsr-helpers/node_modules/babel-polyfill/node_modules/core-js'

npm ERR! Maximum call stack size exceeded

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/developer/.npm/_logs/2018-03-01T21_00_59_918Z-debug.log
```

I suppose, that the error occurs, because of:

```
"fsr-helpers": "file:../../fsr-helpers"
```

in the `devDependencies`. The structure of the folder looks like: 
[image]

and the content of the package.json is:

```
{
  "name": "fsr-helpers",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "15.5.4",
    "react-dom": "15.5.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest src --watch",
    "compile": "./node_modules/.bin/babel -d dist/ src/"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "6.24.0",
    "babel-core": "6.24.0",
    "babel-jest": "19.0.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs": "6.24.0",
    "babel-preset-es2016": "6.22.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "6.23.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "6.22.0",
    "enzyme": "2.8.2",
    "jest": "19.0.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.0.0"
  }
}
```

Why do I get the error:

```
Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

What does `"fsr-helpers": "file:../../fsr-helpers"` mean?

Comment: I think you should be more worried about `npm ERR! Maximum call stack size exceeded` as this is an error but, `npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY` is a warning. and maximum call stack error occurs from your code when a function calls itself continuously and exceeds the browser's call stack capacity.

Answer (score 0):

The *"file:"* syntax is a way to use local path to a package: https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#local-paths

In your case it is looking for package the 2 levels up from the package.json (../../)
It should be `file:./fsr-helpers` instead if I read your folder structure correctly (in a folder directly inside your project).